# configure ReporteRs to get grayscale lattice plots

Tags: r, powerpoint, lattice, grayscale, reporters

is there a comforable way to get *grayscale* trellis plots with ReportRs? `trellis.device(color=FALSE)` seems not to work here

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(lattice)

trellis.device(color=FALSE) # set grayscale

p <- xyplot(decrease ~ treatment, OrchardSprays, groups = rowpos,
            auto.key =list(space = "right"))

print(p) # ok, grayscale

doc = pptx("Test")
doc = addSlide(doc, "Title and Content")
doc = addPlot(doc, fun = print, x = p)  # not ok, colored
writeDoc(doc, "test.pptx")
```

here

[image]

instead of

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is OK when using trellis.par.set. See below:

```
library(ReporteRs)
library(lattice)

p <- xyplot(decrease ~ treatment, OrchardSprays, groups = rowpos,
            auto.key =list(space = "right"))

ltheme <- standard.theme(color = FALSE) 

doc = pptx("Test")
doc = addSlide(doc, "Title and Content")
doc = addPlot(doc, fun = {
  trellis.par.set(ltheme)
  print(p)
}) 
writeDoc(doc, "test.pptx")
```